# Day Trade $25,000 again

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-markets, day-trading

If I have a margin Day Trade account, after some transactions/tradings there is only $25,000 cash in this account now.

There are some cases for this Day Trade account I need to know its status. Please help:

case 1: If I buy $10,000 worth of stocks in the morning, only $15,000 cash left, the above account still meets the $25,000 requirement, right?

case 2: If the stocks go down in the afternoon, at the end of the trading day, that $10,000 worth of stocks only has a $9,000 market value, the above account will get a call/warning about the $25,000 requirement, telling me that account needs more cash?

case 3: If I spend all $25,000 cash on stocks, now no cash left, but the market value of these stocks is above $25,000, does the above account still meet the $25,000 requirement? how about if the market value is less than $25,000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some clarification first because it is not clear how many day trades you made and in what time period.

You can only trade settled cash in a  CASH ACCOUNT.  That means that with T+2, the funds from a sale will not be available for two days.  There is no limit to how many day trades you can make in a cash account as long as you are using settled funds.

A pattern day trader is a person who executes 4 or more day trades (options and equities) in a rolling FIVE business day period in a MARGIN account, provided the number of day trades are more than six percent of the customer's total trading activity for that same five-day period.  If you are  a pattern day trader then you are subject to the $25k minimum.

> case 1: If I buy $10,000 worth of stocks in the morning, only $15,000 cash left, the above account still meets the $25,000 requirement, right?

You meet the $25k requirement as long as the value of the stocks do not drop.

> case 2: If the stocks go down in the afternoon, at the end of the trading day, that $10,000 worth of stocks only has a $9,000 market value, the above account will get a call/warning about the $25,000 requirement, telling me that account needs more cash?

That is correct.  You will be restricted from further day trading until you add cash or marginable securities, restoring the $25k minimum.

> case 3: If I spend all $25,000 cash on stocks, now no cash left, but the market value of these stocks is above $25,000, does the above account still meet the $25,000 requirement? how about if the market value is less than $25,000?

This question is just combining the questions asked in case 1 and case 2. The same answers apply.